# How to return distinct node-pair in Neo4j Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have Node type: Person and Neighborhood. When trying to find the persons LIVES in the same neighborhood, I have the persons appeared twice, in different order.

```
MATCH (p1:Person)-[n1:LIVES]-(n:Neighborhood)-[n2:LIVES]-(p2:Person)  
RETURN n.name, p1.name, p2.name
```

returns:

```
"Riverdale", "Paul", "James"
"Riverdale", "Paul", "Mary"
"Riverdale", "James", "Paul"
"Riverdale", "Mary", "Paul"
"Newton", "Zoe", "Harry"
"Newton", "Harry", "Zoe"
...
```

How can I deduplicate the result set to have the pair appear only once?

```
"Riverdale", "Paul", "James"
"Riverdale", "Paul", "Mary"
"Newton", "Zoe", "Harry"
...
```

I tried DISTINCT but it did not work as the list is ordered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern matches both ways so to eliminate one half of the responses you can add a `WHERE` clause that specifies the `id()` of one of the `Person` nodes is greater than the other.

```
MATCH (p1:Person)-[n1:LIVES]-(n:Neighborhood)-[n2:LIVES]-(p2:Person)  
WHERE id(p1) > id(p2)
RETURN n.name, p1.name, p2.name
```